# Regex only match with set of numbers

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have set of numbers have ID number here. Digit in center `-01-` must be match with `01,21,22,23,24,02`. Currently, it just accept whatever value as long it's 2 digit. It just need to accept these set of numbers `01,21,22,23,24,02`. Any idea?

```
[0-9]{2}(([0-0]{1}[1-9]{1})|([1-1]{1}[0-2]{1}))(([0-0]{1}[1-9]{1})|([1-2]{1}[0-9]{1})|[3-3]{1}[0-1]{1})-[01|21|23|24|01]{2}-[0-9]{4}
```

ID format

```
880101-01-5332
```

Here is link for my sample regex: https://regex101.com/r/GYJ6by/2

Comment: you try with `^[0-9]{6}-(01|21|22|23|24|02)-[0-9]{4}$`

Comment: `[01|21|23|24|01]` is a character class which _“matches a single character in the list `01|234`”_, so either `0`, `1`, `|`, `2`, `3` or `4`, two characters long, **as explained by RegEx101 itself**. You’re also missing two numbers and repeating one. So what you want is `(?:01|02|21|22|23|24)`, without the `{2}`.

Comment: @Xufox thanks for the explanation. It's working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parentheses for those limited options. `[]` is for a character set, but for specific options, you can use `(foo|bar|baz)`.

```
[0-9]{2}(([0-0]{1}[1-9]{1})|([1-1]{1}[0-2]{1}))(([0-0]{1}[1-9]{1})|([1-2]{1}[0-9]{1})|[3-3]{1}[0-1]{1})-(01|21|23|24|01)-[0-9]{4}
```